# MY SQL Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint on forward engineering

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to forward my table from my MYSQL Workbench to my DB but it just won't work.
Server Database is AWS RDS MYSQL 5.7.33, to which I have set my model settings as well.
I am using the MYSQL Forward Engineer to push my settings to the server.

M

It throws

ERROR: Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

on

```
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `ama_g_eu`.`gift_tags`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ama_g_eu`.`gift_tags` (
      `tag_id` INT NOT NULL,
      `gift_id` INT NOT NULL,
      INDEX `id_idx` (`tag_id` ASC),
      INDEX `id_idx1` (`gift_id` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`)
        REFERENCES `ama_g_eu`.`tags` (`id`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `id`
        FOREIGN KEY (`gift_id`)
        REFERENCES `ama_g_eu`.`gifts` (`id`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying two create to constraints named `id`:

`` CONSTRAINT `id` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) ``

and

`` CONSTRAINT `id` FOREIGN KEY (`gift_id`) ``

Try changing one or both of the names.

Comment: ...or one could remove all of the `CONSTRAINT \`id\`` and the DB will create default constraints, if one does not care what the default names may be. I commented-out all of the constraints by doing: `-- CONSTRAINT \`id\`` and no errors, the DB created with all tables.